# laravel: not printing accurate error message (validation.required)

Tags: php, laravel

Any idea why it's not displaying the exact error message?

The message is shown as

```
validation.required
```

Comment: You dont have lang file with name validation and translation with key required.

Comment: I do have the lang file "validation.php" and the key name is same as well

Comment: And is it array, which you return in this file? Is content of validation.php like `<?php return array('required' => 'This input is required'); //....` and is placed in the lang directory in resources?

Comment: yes.

   `return [
 'required'             => 'The :attribute field is required.',
    'required_if'          => 'The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.',
    'required_unless'      => 'The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.',
]`

Comment: Oh, im. stupid. You just have to place it in trans function {{trans($variable)}}, where $variable contains shown string "validation.required"

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: if you have validation errors in variable $errors, then in view you make `@foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ trans($error) }}</li> @enndforeach`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have deleted `resources/lang` folder resource. That is why it is not being able to read the appropriate message for current language.

If you don't want to write all messages by yourself every time you write a validation, I suggest you restore that folder from other freshly installed copy of laravel.

If you are okay with it you can specify the messages right after validation rules.

Ex.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    ...
], [
    'name.required' => 'Please enter your name',
    ...
]);
```

This way you can also customise your messages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do have the folder resources/lang

_it contains:_
1. auth.php
2. pagination.php
3. password.php
4. validation.php

Comment: Well, it should contain a folder `en` and inside that there should be `validation.php` and others

Comment: Please look into `config/app.php` and verify if `'locale' => 'en'` & `'fallback_locale' => 'en'` is set.